# JPA CASCADE PERSIST and Spring CrudRepository

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

(Note: Edited to add code to reproduce behaviour)

I have the following three entities

```
@Entity
public class ClassA {
  @Id private UUID id = UUIDGenerator.generate();
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classA", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
  List<ClassB> classBs= new ArrayList<>();
 //setters and getters
 }

@Entity
public class ClassB {
  @Id private UUID id = UUIDGenerator.generate();

  @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REMOVE},
        orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "classB")
  private ClassC classC;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "classA_id")
  private ClassA classA;
  // setters and getters

@Entity
public class ClassC {
  @Id private UUID id = UUIDGenerator.generate();
  @OneToOne //(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId
  private ClassB classB;
  //setters and getters
}

public interface ClassARepository extends CrudRepository<ClassA, UUID> {}

//Example code to reproduce
ClassC classC_1 = new ClassC();
ClassC classC_2 = new ClassC();
ClassB classB_1 = new ClassB();
ClassB classB_2 = new ClassB();
classC_1.setClassB(classB_1);
classC_2.setClassB(classB_2);
classB_1.setClassC(classC_1);
classB_2.setClassC(classC_2);
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
classB_1.setClassA(classA);
classB_2.setClassA(classA);

classA.getClassBs().add(classB_1);
classA.getClassBs().add(classB_2);

classARepository.save(classA);
```

I am using Spring Boot and CRUD repository. The first time I try to save an entity of type A, I expect that due to the `CascadeType.PERSIST` annotation all the hierarchy of classes A, B and C will be saved. However this is not the case and I get back a 
`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find classB with id ...`

If I change the `@OneToMany` cascade type to  `CascadeType.ALL` then classA and classB are saved but not classC. If I change all cascade types to ALL then everything is saved.

However, I want to cascade the save operation, only when a new entity is created and not when merged, which I assume that is exactly what PERSIST means. Can someone explain the above behaviour and how can I achieve what I want?

Regards

Comment: To let others reproduce please add example code how you create and persist these entities.

Comment: Added code, so that you can more easily reproduce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question:

It seems that the problem lies with the id generation strategy. In this case I generate the Id before storing in the repository and this causes trouble. Specifically

From what I could see `SimpleJpaRepository` has this code

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        this.em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return this.em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

where the decision of whether an entity is new is from `JpaPersistableEntityInformation` here:

```
public boolean isNew(T entity) {
    return entity.isNew();
}
```

and `entity.isNew()` is defined as follows:

```
@Transient
public boolean isNew() {
    return null == this.getId();
}
```

So, in other words, the id generation strategy actually affects the result from the cascade. And as a matter of fact I validated my assumption by changing everywhere the ids to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

and, voila, everything works.

Not an ideal situation, but at least I know why it is happening. So, PERSIST basically applies only to db-generated IDs? Seems strange, so if anyone has a suggestion on how to overcome this problem, let us know.

Regards